# Is there a good keyboard reference for bricklink Studio?

Tags: mac, bricklink-studio

I'm looking for a good keyboard reference card for Bricklink Studio.  I found [this help article on the official site](https://studiohelp.bricklink.com/hc/en-us/articles/5706320095255-Shortcuts) but it doesn't print out very nicely.  I'd like something more like a reference card from the old days.  If it was Mac-focused that'd be great too, but most of the keystrokes aren't that different between the platforms anyway.  Have you seen anything like what I'm describing?